# API Migration using wso2 apictl

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Can we export and import multiple apis at the same time in different environments using wso2 apictl tool?

Answer (score 2):

We can export multiple APIs at once using the WSO2 API Manager apictl tool. Please refer [1]. That is, you can export all APIs of a particular tenant using the command given in [1]. But importing multiple APIs is not supported.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-controller/migrating-apis-to-different-environments/#export-all-the-apis-of-a-tenant-at-once

Comment: thanks tharika for your response..but can we export or import like two, three apis like number of apis' of our choice?

Comment: Hi Sanket, no, that capability is not available in the apictl tool.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Tharika has mentioned, APICTL can **only** be used to migrate APIs in between **different environments of the same APIM version**. Migrating APIs across different APIM versions is not supported.